# How do I achieve the effect in these photos with photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter

They did an awesome job of blending their website colors to the photos. I'm trying to figure out how to do the same.

[image]

Comment: Related but not identical - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/102446/57929

Comment: You could convert to Greyscale, and then convert to Duotone - [see example here](https://imgur.com/a/oV9uCTJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **Gradient Map** to achieve a similar effect. It basically converts your image to grayscale and maps the lightness of the image to a gradient of your choice.

1. In the *Layers* panel, make a *Gradient Map* adjustment layer.
2. In the *Properties* panel, click the gradient.
3. Double-click the leftmost *Color Stop*, choose the wanted color for the darkest areas and click *OK*.
4. Double-click the rightmost *Color Stop*, choose the wanted color for the lightest areas and click *OK*.
5. Click *OK* and you're done!

The image might look a little flat after this treatment since the span from the darkest to the lightest color is less than in an ordinary B/W image. You might need to add some adjustment layers *below* the *Gradient Map* layer to increase the contrast of the image before coloring.

[image]

The gradient of the *Gradient Map* can be used for many different things. More color stops can be added and the transition between each of them can be customized. You can find inspiration in the presets.

Comment: ...as explained in the duplicate I proposed 

Comment: @Vincent, you might be right it's a duplicate, but I'm not sure. The result is quite different. The duplicate is really about making a "mono-hue" image which could be achieved by just multiplying a color on top of a grayscale image. This is about having different hues for the dark and light areas.

Answer (score 0):

select photo.

from adjustment layer choose solid.

pick your color and creat clipping mask.

and reduce the 'clipping mask' layer opacity from layer panel..

kindly check the attached photo and the layer hierarchy.

hope it will help you.

[image]

Comment: This is basically just an overlay

Comment: so mine wont serve the purpose?